# How do I bind the escape key to close this window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a little program that I've cobbled together to download patents.  I'd like to bind the escape key to a function to close the window, but I don't really know how to make this happen.  I've bound the escape key to a "quit" function, but can someone help me figure out how to write the function to close the text input window?

I'm a noob.

```
from Tkinter import *
import urllib

master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()


def patdload(self, event=None): 
    allnums = e.get()
    index = 0
    test = allnums.find('.')
    if test > 0:
        sep = 0
        while sep != -1:
            sep = allnums.find('.', index) 
            if sep != -1:
                patno = allnums[index:sep]
            elif sep == -1:
                patno = allnums[index:]

            #patno = e.get()
            paturl = "http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US" + patno + ".pdf"
            urllib.urlretrieve (paturl, (patno + ".pdf"))
            index = sep + 1


    else:
        patno = e.get()
        paturl = "http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US" + patno + ".pdf"
        urllib.urlretrieve (paturl, (patno + ".pdf"))


def quit #help#:

master.bind('<Return>', patdload)

master.bind('<Escape>',quit)



#b = Button(master, text = "GET", width = 10, command = patdload)
#b.pack()


mainloop()
```

Edit: here's the new error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\PatentGet.py", line 42, in <lambda>
master.bind('<Escape>', lambda x: close())
File "C:\Python27\PatentGet.py", line 39, in close
master.widthdraw() # if you want to bring it back
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1894, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: widthdraw
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, quit is a built-in method so I'd use another name. Otherwise, here's the function:

```
import sys

def close(event):
    master.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
    sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing

master.bind('<Escape>', close)
```

Comment: Thanks - I gave that a shot, but now I'm getting the following error: 

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: close() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: No, sorry - it doesn't work.  My problem was copying and pasting the error into the comment.  The error is in "line 1532".  I edited the first comment to include the error text.

Comment: here! whats your idea?

Comment: I figured out. Forgot that all event callbacks need an argument. Mark as answer if you can. This will definitely work.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I am not sure if it a good idea to do what you did. You are hiding the `master` and stopping the execution of the script, instead of closing/destroying the window.

Comment: Rinzler, I clearly indicated in comments that he is to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `destroy()` method within lambda expression to safely exit. I have used in `python 3.7.x`.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda x: root.destroy())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Question is old. So add the version you use where this function is implemented by updating your answer. End of Review.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the safer exit method than `sys.exit()`. In my example, `root.destroy()` is a safe, dependable way to exit your Tkinter app. destroy() just terminates the mainloop and deletes all widgets. So it seems to be safer if you call your app from another Tkinter app, or if you have multiple mainloops.

```
import tkinter as tk

def exit(event):
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind("<Escape>", exit)
root.mainloop()
```